# visual basic when form loads, make something show

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Trying to make Label1 show when the form loads, after a delay. Then after Label1 shows, trying to make Label2 show, after a further delay. Neither will work with either sleeping or delaying.

Here is my code:

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Label1.Show()
    Delay(2)

    Label2.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Move everything in the Form_Shown event. In Form_Load your form is not visible.

Comment: How do you create the two labels?

Answer (score 2):

This ended up working:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.Visible = False
    Button2.Visible = False


End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Show(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Delay(5)
    Button1.Visible = True
    Delay(5)
    Button2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to initialize the labels as hidden when the form loads, then when the form is **SHOWN** you would then run your code...

EDIT: I realized that OP wanted to show the labels in succession and not all at once after a delay...

```
    public int i = 1; // public variable as a counter

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Visible = false; // start the labels as not visible.
        label2.Visible = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1.Start(); // start up the timer.
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // initialize a timer that iterates through the labels provided
        // and set them to visible.
        while(i <= 2)
        {

            Label test = (Label)this.Controls["label" + i.ToString()];
            test.Visible = true;
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Question is tagged with VB(and judging from the OP's code, is indeed what is being used), why use C# for your answer?